# How to pass different set of data to two different mappers of the same job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I have one Single Mapper , say SingleGroupIdentifierMapper.java

Now this is a generic mapper which does all the filtration on a single line of mapper-input value/record based on property file (containing filters and key-value field indexes) passed to it from the driver class using cache.

Only the reducer business logic is is different and has been implemented keeping the mapper logic generic and to be implemented using the PropertyFile as mentioned above.

Now my problem statement is I have input from multiple Sources now, having different formats. That means I have to do some thing like

```
 MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/inputA"),TextInputFormat.class, SingleGroupIdentifierMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/inputB"),TextInputFormat.class, SingleGroupIdentifierMapper.class);
```

But the cached property file which I pass from the driver class to the mapper for implementing filter based on field indexes is common, So how can I pass two different property file to the same mapper, where if it processes, say Input A, then it will use PropertyFileA (to filter and create key value pair) and if it processes, say Input B then it will use PropertyFileB (to filter and create key value pair).

It is possible to change the Generic Code of the Mapper to take care of this scenario BUT how to approach this problem in the Generic Class and how to identify  in the same Mapper Class if the input is from inputA/inputB and accordingly apply the propertyFile Configuration on the data.

Can we pass arguments to the constructor of this mapper class to specify it is from inputB or it needs to read which property file in cache.?

Eg Something like :

MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/inputB"),TextInputFormat.class, **args[]**, SingleGroupIdentifierMapper.class);

where args[] is passed to the SingleGroupIdentifierMapper class's constructor which we define to take as input and set it as a attribure.

Any thoughts or expertise is most welcomed.

Hope I was able to express my problem clearly, kindly ask me in case there needs to be more clarity in the question.

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers :)

Comment: So you will be having n input file paths, and n cached property files. And you are planning to send them all as part jar command?

Comment: I am sending them as jobConf.setString(configFileKey,JsonStringOfConfigFile)  where JsonStringOfConfigFile is nothing but a JsonString of the Key value pairs of the Config File Which I convert to object in my Common-Mapper getting multiple inputs from different folders

Comment: Is it Possible to get the Input File Path in my Mapper?!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MultipleInputs is not that flexible. But there is a workaround which matches InputSplit paths to the property files in the setup method of the Mapper. If you are not using any sort of Combine*Format, than a single mapper will process a single split from a single file:

1. When adding prop files into cache use /propfile_1#PROPS_A and /propfile_2#PROPS_B
2. Add input path into job.getConfiguration().set("PROPS_A", "/inputA") and job.getConfiguration().set("PROPS_B", "/inputB")
3. In the Mapper.setup(Context context) method, use context.getInputSplit().toString() to get the path of the split. Than match it to the paths saved in the context.getConfiguration().get("PROPS_A") or PROPS_B

If you are using some Combine*Format, than you would need to extend it, override getSplits that use information from the JobContext to build the PathFilter[] and call createPool, which will create splits that contain files from the same group (inputA or inputB).